# Why not always use (objectClass=*) in the LDAP search filter?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I created the following filter for search users in Active Directory:

```
(&(objectClass=*)(|(sAMAccountName=u)(userPrincipalName=u))
```

It is possible to create more qualified filter:

```
(&(objectClass=person)(|(sAMAccountName=u)(userPrincipalName=u))
```

The question is why?

What benefits of using specified class `person`?

Is it possible that the same directory contain object where `objectClass` is not `person` but the following is true `(|(sAMAccountName=u)(userPrincipalName=u))`?

Why not always use `(objectClass=*)` in the LDAP search filter?

Comment: Why? Every object has an objectClass. What's the point of testing that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(objectClass=*)` is a present filter used to filter out objects that have no populated `objectClass` ... which is none, since all LDAP objects have at least one structural objectClass, hence the filter component in the first filter is unnecessary and may even slow down the search, depending on the server configuration.

The first filter in your question might cause the server to make comparisons using matching rules that are unnecessary. The second filter is a better filter from a performance perspective, assuming that an index for objectClass equality has been created on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1). 
We want to support not only Active Directory.
I get from your answer and from the article the following and cope you will approve it:
1) Required to use at least the `(objectClass=*)` present filter to be able to work with all LDAPs (e.g. SUN LDAP).
2) A filter with the `(objectClass=*)` present filter returns correct result for any LDAP (and not only for Active Directory). 
3) Using the `(objectClass=person)` equality filter improves performance.

Comment: Yes. However, LDAP clients must not be written with any bias towards a server. LDAP clients should be written using code that conforms to LDAP standards, and they should be written as if the coder does not know which brand of LDAP server is used. To do otherwise results in fragile, brittle code which might have to be changed when the server vendor changes - when the vendor changes the way the server responds to LDAP requests.

Comment: Or the code should be written to isolate any server-dependent code as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a holdover from generic LDAP services, where in priniciple any object could share the same attribute with the same value, but be of different object classes.

However, Active Directory has a limitation that sAMAccountName must be unique within the domain, across all object classes.   And only 4 object classes should have the attribute?  (Users, groups, printers, and workstations I think).

So you could most likely just query for 
`(|(sAMAccountName=u)(userPrincipalName=u))`

without the objectclass filter at all.